# Multi-condition OR in one AND with Zend_Db_Select

Tags: sql, database, zend-framework

I use Zend_Db_Select and I want to make multi-condition in an AND, but don't know if it's possible or not... I search in many forums but don't find any answer...

I want to have a query like this :

```
SELECT
    `t`.*
FROM
    `T_table` AS `t`
WHERE
    (t.id = '123456')
AND (
    (t.param = 'yyy')
    OR (t.param = 'xxx')
    OR (....)
)
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are intending to check a single field against multi-values, use IN clause

```
$select->where('t.id = ?', '123456')
       ->where('t.param IN(?)', array('value1', 'value2', 'value3'));
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue as you in one of my project. Here how it worked for me

```
$select = $this->_table->select()
                        ->from(array('t' => 'T_table'); 
$select->where('t.id = ?', '123456');
$select->where('t.param =' . $varY . ' OR t.param = ' . $varX);
```

Basically, you're explicitly writing the OR inside a select->where().